# Gitlab version upgrade from 14.0.5 to 15.0.4 - DB Migration Error

Tags: gitlab, devops

I tried to upgrade 14.0.5 to 15.0.4, got follwing errors.

while run gitlab-rake reconfigure command getting .. rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ....

while run gitlab-rake db:migrage command getting ...  pg::duplicateschema: error: schema "gitlab_partitions_dynamic" already exists

***Operating system name: ubuntu 20.04 & Architecture: x86_64 & Ruby version: 2.7.5p203

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upgrade directly between these two versions. You must follow the [upgrade path](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#upgrade-paths). You should try again following the proper upgrade path. Also make sure you read the version-specific notes, too and allow for background migrations to complete at each stop in the upgrade path.

For you, that would be: `14.0.12` -> `14.3.6` -> `14.9.5` -> `14.10.Z` -> `15.0.Z`

Comment: I tried to updgrade the 14.0.12 verion but getting error

Comment: rails_migration[gitlab-rails] (gitlab::database_migrations line 51) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/resources/rails_migration.rb line 16) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20220718-1322478-6fu81x" ----
STDOUT: WARNING: Active Record does not support composite primary key.
audit_events has composite primary key. Composite primary key is ignored.
rake aborted!

Comment: == 20200722202318 BackfillPartitionedAuditEvents: migrating ===================
-- transaction_open?()
   -> 0.0000s
WARNING: Active Record does not support composite primary key.audit_events has composite primary key. Composite primary key is ignored.
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Comment: Caused by:
ArgumentError: the column: argument must be set to a column name to use for ordering rows
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/concerns/